# Interpolation and increasing spatial resolution of netfdf data

Tags: python, geospatial, netcdf, python-xarray

How can I increase the resolution of netfdf data for feeding to CNN in python?
Is there any function in xarray to do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are examples of interpolation with xarray on their website: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @drcrisp I am also looking to like regrid the data. Currently my data has latitude(-90,90,0.25) and longitude(0,360,0.25). i would like to convert it to latitude(-90,90,0.125) and longitude(0,360,0.125). And then interpolate the same. End goal being to improve spatial resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use xarray interpolation to achieve what you want. You have to define the new latitude and longitude you'd like to interpolate to and pass it to the xarray interp function. See example below

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create sample data
dx  = 0.25
lon = np.arange(0, 360, dx)
lat = np.arange(-90, 90+dx, dx)
data = 10 * np.random.rand(len(lat), len(lon))
data_set = xr.Dataset({"temp": (["lat", "lon"], data)},
                 coords={"lon": lon,"lat": lat})

# Just checking the datasets are not empty
print(data_set)

# Create new lat and lon
dx_new = 0.125
newlon = np.arange(0, 360, dx_new)
newlat = np.arange(-90, 90+dx_new, dx_new)

# Interpolate
data_set_interp = data_set.interp(lat=newlat, lon=newlon)

# Check output
print(data_set_interp)
```